# Rendering an Object more than once

Tags: c++, object, rendering, shader, directx-11

Right now I'm facing the issue of rendering the same objects more than once in Directx 11, as the object has:

- A diffuse shader
- A directional lighting shader
- A texture shader

Now the final color should be all of them somehow put together, maybe something like this:

- Render Diffuse
- Render Texture
- Render Directional

Final Color = (Diffuse + Texture) * Lighting // Not sure about this though

But how can this be archieved? Without the EFFECTS FRAMEWORK!

Comment: You mean you want _copies_ of the same object be rendered in the same scene, simultaneously?

Comment: Yes, kind of i guess. But with different shadings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved in DirectX11 a couple of ways. The first is by making an "uber shader".  This means to do diffuse, texture and lighting in the same shader. The second is to use dynamic shader linking and dynamically link together unique diffuse/texture/lighting shaders at runtime. The June 2010 sdk has a good example of dynamic shader linking. Also the usual combination of colors is:

Final Color = Diffuse * Texture * Lighting